# Jackson serialization issue with JSON/UTF-8 and unicode 2022

Tags: java, json, encoding, utf-8, jackson

Our web client allows users to enter text, it is normally from MS Word and contains bullet points. The bullet points are the 2022 unicode character but do not serialize correctly when being returned from the service to the client.

According to the documentation, utf-8 is the default for jackson serialization. We have found an issue with it dealing with the unicode bullet point. The following example demonstrates this:

```
   @POST
   @Path("/utfBullet1")
   @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
   public String getUTFBullet() throws UnsupportedEncodingException;

   @POST
   @Path("/utfBullet1")
   @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
   public String getUTFBullet2() throws UnsupportedEncodingException;

   @Override
   public String getUTFBullet() throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
          // TODO Auto-generated method stub
          String s = Character.toString((char)0X2022);
          return s;
   }

   @Override
   public String getUTFBullet2() throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
          // TODO Auto-generated method stub
          return this.getUTFBullet();
   }
```

Specifying the charset with @Produces("application/json;charset=utf-8") does not work, we get the unicode replacement character ?, charset=CP-1252 does work however we want to preserve utf-8.

Suggestions?

Comment: Doesn't help your problem, but you don't need to do `(char)0X2022`. You can just do `\u2022`. Same thing with slightly nicer syntax. :)